# Python produce True False output after comparing two indexes from different dataframes using one line code

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, if-statement

I have two data frames as given below

small_df =

```
index    data1
2         123
3         436
```

big_df =

```
index    data1
0          78
1          67
2          13
3          46
```

I want to compare check if any index of `small_df` present in `big_df` using a one line code and produce True or False. 
My code:

```
 big_idx  = [True for i in small_df.index if i in big_df.index]
```

My present output

```
big_idx = [True True]
```

My expected output

```
big_idx = [False False True True]
```

How to insert False in my code? I tried following code but not successful.

```
[True for i in small_df.index if i in big_df.index else False]
```

Comment: try `[True for i in big_df.index if i in small_df.index]`

Comment: @RandyMaldonado I tried this. Looks like I need to mention False as well in the code. I dont know where to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line can be fixed fairly easy:

```
all(i in big_df.index for i in small_df.index)
```

However, there is a better approach:

```
small_df.index.difference(big_df.index)
```

This will return index elements from `small_df` that are not in `big_df`. Just check if its length is zero.

Comment: How do we get True/False list?

Comment: @Mainland: just remove the `all` from Marat's first answer and replace it with regular list comprehension.

Comment: @Mainland: you were already using list comprehension in your code in the question. I'd suggest looking into basic Python tutorials before you start working with numpy/pandas.

Comment: @LieRyan I got it. Just replaced them with `[ ]' at end and now it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`[True if i in small_df.index else False for i in big_df.index]`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the index to list and then to set and then use intersection.

```
A= set(small_df.index.tolist())
B= set(bid_df.index.tolist())
print(len(A.intersection(B)) > 0)
```